# Unable to compile C extensions for clickhouse-connect python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, module, clickhouse

Unexpectedly stuck on installation of python module **clickhouse-connect**, with this error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: clickhouse-connect
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for clickhouse-connect ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-req-build-4fl5kcjv/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-o14i2v_m --python-tag cp37:
  Using Cython 3.0.0b1to build cython modules
  Unable to compile C extensions for faster performance due to usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help
  
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel', will use pure Python
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help
```

And absolutely no ideas :(

Details:

- Python 3.7.3 (default, Oct 31 2022, 14:04:00)  [GCC 8.3.0] on linux
- pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
- cython, wheel, python3-dev - installed.
- clickhouse-connect using pure Python installed successfully.

I have tried to build module from sources ([github](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-connect)), but again, no luck.

Comment: Your version of `pip` is *way* out of date. Run `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: That easy!
Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm curious -- what operating system are you running?  `pip install clickhouse-connect` should just install the precompiled binary wheels in 99% of cases.  (I'm the author of clickhouse-connect)

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). But it's severely tuned/modified corporate development server, so I don't think that you should take it in mind, anything unexpected may occur there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MattDMo posted in comments, i have outdated pip.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Solved the problem.